# Set environment variable for all deployments or pods in cluster

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, amazon-eks, http-proxy, podspec

I created EKS cluster and now i need to add http_proxy/http_proxies and no_proxy as environment variable to all 300 deployments. I created a config map with the variables. Is there a way to update all pods simultaneously without doing it one by one? And if yes how can i do it? My config map name is proxy-environment-variables.

Thank you for the help and assistance!

BR,

Martin

```
Name:         proxy-environment-variables
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
HTTPS_PROXY:
----
http://10.16.11.10:8080
HTTP_PROXY:
----
http://10.16.11.10:8080
NO_PROXY:
----
169.254.169.254,127.0.0.1,localhost,10.0.0.0/8
http_proxy:
----
http://10.16.11.10:8080
https_proxy:
----
http://10.16.11.10:8080
no_proxy:
----
169.254.169.254,127.0.0.1,localhost,10.0.0.0/8

BinaryData
====

Events:  <none>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `set env` to update the environment variable into the deployment:

```
kubectl set env deployment --all  --from=configmap/my-env-config
```

Example: The following example is demonstrating if there are multiple deployments, how to add env variables to their pods.

// I have the following deployments:

```
kubectl get deployment
NAME    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
dep-1   1/1     1            1           5m21s
dep-2   1/1     1            1           41m
dep-4   1/1     1            1           3m17s
```

// their respective pods:

```
kubectl get pod
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
dep-1-84fcdf5-wblsm      1/1     Running   0          2m8s
dep-2-84fcdf5-qfbd5      1/1     Running   0          3m4s
dep-4-6cf4dcf794-wk476   1/1     Running   0          4s
```

// my config map:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  HTTP_PROXY: https://1.2.3.4:1234
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-05-04T16:52:00Z"
  name: my-env-config
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1002232"
  uid: c8606312-90c6-45cf-86f0-f4f874f19909
```

// HTTP_PROXY env variable is **already** set in dep-1

```
kubectl exec -it dep-1-84fcdf5-wblsm -- printenv HTTP_PROXY
https://1.2.3.4:1234
```

// HTTP_PROXY env variable is **already** set in dep-2

```
kubectl exec -it dep-2-84fcdf5-qfbd5 -- printenv HTTP_PROXY
https://1.2.3.4:1234
```

// HTTP_PROXY env variable is **not** set in dep-4, **this is our focus**

```
kubectl exec -it dep-4-6cf4dcf794-wk476 -- printenv HTTP_PROXY
command terminated with exit code 1
```

// **SOLUTION**: Setting env for all the deployments(`--all`) from a config map called `my-env-config`)

```
 kubectl set env deployment --all  --from=configmap/my-env-config
deployment.apps/dep-4 env updated
```

//Note the age of the pods, only dep-4's pod age is altered

```
kubectl get pod
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
dep-1-84fcdf5-wblsm      1/1     Running   0          3m40s
dep-2-84fcdf5-qfbd5      1/1     Running   0          4m36s
dep-4-59d5cfd48d-2tbbm   1/1     Running   0          5s
```

// now HTTP_PROXY is set in dep-4's pod.

```
kubectl exec -it dep-4-59d5cfd48d-2tbbm -- printenv HTTP_PROXY
https://1.2.3.4:1234
```